# How to calculate bearing value between two points on ground without knowing one of the two points geo location?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am trying to write a program which can calculate geo location of a pixel point (with x and y coordinates) in an image captured by a surveillance camera which is fixed at some distance from that real life point (pointing at that point from image) and at some height from ground. to calculate distance between camera and that point in real life first I calculated distance between origin and that location of pixel point in image using distance formula and by knowing real life distance covered in a pixel point in image, I multiplied that distance value with the value find by using distance formula between origin and that point in image to get real life distance between two points and later on to give some height to camera from ground I used to pythogoras theorem to calculate hypteneuse i.e. distance between that point in real life (from the point of that image) and a camera at some height. Now that I calcualted distance between camera and point and I also know geo location of point where camera is placed, my task is to calculate geo coordinates of that real life point (from the point of that image) knowing these 2 things.

Following is code for calcualting distance:

```
double onePixelDistance = realLifeGroundDist/groundY;
// double distBtwPixels = sqrt(pow(px - ((x/2)-1), 2) + pow(py - (y-1), 2) * 1);

// Distance formula to calculate dist btw origin and (px,py) pixel
double distBtwPixels = sqrt(pow(px - (x-1), 2) + pow(py - ((y/2)-1), 2) * 1);

//translating pixel distance to real life distance
double h = distBtwPixels * onePixelDistance;

//considering that camera is placed above ground at some height i.e. cameraHeight variable at angle = 90deg and calculating distance btw that point and camera i.e. hypteneuse
double realLifeDist = sqrt(pow(h, 2) + pow(cameraHeight, 2));

cout<<"Distance between camera and px and py coordinates in image = "<<realLifeDist;
```

Moreover, I've also tried to find geo location of point using following which I've implemented by following algorithm but my main challenge here that I don't know value of bearing between point where camera is located and real life point for which we've to find geo coordinates. And all I can find on internet is that we'd have to know geo location of both points earlier to get bearing value between two points which is not possible.

```
double cameraLatitude, cameraLongitude; //geo-location of camera
double distance, bearing; //distance between camera and point, bearing of point
double pointLatitude, pointLongitude; //geo-coordinates of point

// input camera geo-location
std::cout << "Enter camera latitude: ";
std::cin >> cameraLatitude;
std::cout << "Enter camera longitude: ";
std::cin >> cameraLongitude;

// input distance and bearing of point
std::cout << "Enter distance to point (in meters): ";
std::cin >> distance;
std::cout << "Enter bearing of point (in degrees): ";
std::cin >> bearing;

// convert bearing to radians
double bearingRad = bearing * (M_PI / 180);

// calculate point geo-coordinates
pointLatitude = asin(sin(cameraLatitude) * cos(distance/6371000) + cos(cameraLatitude) * sin(distance/6371000) * cos(bearingRad));
pointLongitude = cameraLongitude + atan2(sin(bearingRad) * sin(distance/6371000) * cos(cameraLatitude), cos(distance/6371000) - sin(cameraLatitude) * sin(pointLatitude));
```

So, can anyone give me its solution to find bearing or how can I find geo coordinates knowing distance between camera and point, and geo location of camera. Because, only solution I could find on internet to find bearing value between two points is to have geo location of both points, which is not possible to know a point's geo location, because that's my real task to find that out, however I know geo location of camera point. So, is there an easy way to find bearing?

Comment: If you are obtaining real life distance between the camera and the point from a captured image, can you also extract the bearing of the point from the same image?

Comment: Ofc not because I have no idea about direction of 2nd point, I only just know the distance which I've estimated from image's per pixel distance.

Comment: On one hand, (if I haven't missed any known information,) this is like asking about the direction of an arbitrary point $A$ from the origin $O$ on an $xy$-plane, given the length $OA$; $A$ can be at any direction. On the other hand, there was a calibration process to measure the real life distance of one pixel, so you can as well measure the real life direction of one (vertical or horizontal) pixel, in order to answer your question.

Comment: You need another camera.  It would be analogous to a radio direction finding system.